# Postfix extremely slow, lot of mail in maildrop

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, opendkim

Im trying to figure out what's wrong with this cofiguration. I've got a lot of mails in `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop` (around 30k!) and those just dont get away. No error in the logs.

If I try to requeue one of the messages in maildrop, `postsuper -r XXXXXXXXX` just fail silently.

I noticed that if i send an email directly from the server using sendmail (via ssh connection), the mail get into the queue, instead if i send the mail via a client (e.g. thunderbird) the mail get delivered instantly (using the same smtp server obviously; spf and dkim get applyed correctly)

All those "dead mail" in maildrop doesnt appear in qshape:

```
qshape active deferred
                                     T  5 10 20 40 80 160 320 640 1280 1280+
                              TOTAL 11  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0    11
                        example1.it  9  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     9
                       example2.com  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     1
                       example3.com  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     1
```

and if i issue a generic `postsuper -r ALL` i get less of 100 messages requeued.

Any suggestion? my configs:

**main.cf**

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

myhostname = example.com
mydestination = example.com

home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_size_limit = 0
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Example.com)
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
biff = no

inet_interfaces = all

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

recipient_delimiter = +

relayhost =

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain

# Postfix ≥ 2.6 milter_protocol = 6, Postfix ≤ 2.5 milter_protocol = 2

milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"

smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
inet_protocols = ipv4
in_flow_delay = 0s
max_use = 500
destination_concurrency_feedback_debug = yes
smtp_host_lookup = dns,native

qmgr_message_active_limit = 50000
qmgr_message_recipient_limit = 50000
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

# tuning
default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = 5
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_dns_support_level = enabled
default_process_limit = 100

fast_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = 0
fast_destination_recipient_limit = 500
fast_minimum_delivery_slots = 1
fast_delivery_slot_cost = 25
fast_delivery_slot_discount = 5
fast_delivery_slot_loan = 1
fast_recipient_refill_limit = 20000
fast_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = 10

fast_initial_destination_concurrency = 40
fast_destination_concurrency_limit = 150
fast_destination_rate_delay = 0

semifast_initial_destination_concurrency = 20
semifast_destination_concurrency_limit = 60
semifast_destination_rate_delay = 2

medium_initial_destination_concurrency = 10
medium_destination_concurrency_limit = 40
medium_destination_rate_delay = 2

slow_initial_destination_concurrency = 5
slow_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
slow_destination_rate_delay = 2
```

**master.cf**

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================

smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       800       smtpd -v
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       10      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       10     1       qmgr -v
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       1200       smtp -v
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       1200       smtp -v
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
# alla fine la smetto coi milter e vado di classici per postfix
policy-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn user=nobody argv=/usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl

maildrop    unix    -   n   n   -   -   pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#   bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
#scalemail-backend unix -   n   n   -   2   pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}
fast      unix  -       -       -       -       400       smtp
slow      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
medium      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
semifast      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by the library opendkim, even if in the [documentation](http://opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html) is stated that it should rely on `/etc/resolv.conf` (and its been like that as long as I can remember), in my case it was ignored:

> Nameservers (string)
>
> Provides a comma-separated list of IP addresses that are to be used when doing DNS queries to retrieve DKIM keys, VBR records, etc. These override any local defaults built in to the resolver in use, **which may be defined in /etc/resolv.conf or hard-coded into the software**.

Solved adding the `Nameservers` parameter into `/etc/opendkim.conf`.

I'll investigate further to understand [if is a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/opendkim/bugs/260/), or a misconfiguration of mine.